# Terminology questions about a game where one may "save his progress" at the cost of a turn.

Tags: terminology, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

> The game is for $p$ players who each start at square $1$.  Each turn, a player can either roll an $m$-sided dice or place a marker on his current square.  If he rolls $x\in\{2,\ldots, m\}$, he advances $x$ squares.  If he rolls a $1$, he is returned to his most recently placed marker (or, if the player has placed no markers, to square number $1$).  The first player to advance to square $k\geq N\gg m$ wins.

I have two terminology questions:

1. Does this game specifically have a name?
2. Is there a name for the "marker" concept, i.e. how a player may choose to "save his progress" at the cost of advancing $0$ squares that turn?

Comment: Regarding 2, just thinking out loud: How about "lock-in" (as in: "traders are locking in profits")? Or, perhaps borrow something from mountaineering: "anchor"/"anchoring"? (Not even sure if that is the actual mountaineering term.)

Comment: And, perhaps more apt: "back-up"/"backing-up" (as in "backing-up your hard drive).

Comment: Regarding 1: It's a tweaked version of [Snakes and Ladders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snakes_and_Ladders), without snakes and without ladders, but still. There are many such tweaked versions, but I couldn't find yours.

Comment: There are several commercial games of this form (more or less) Greed and Pass the Pigs springing to mind. In these cases the "token" is a score on a pad and players are able to continue their turn until they bank their current score or roll a fail.